# HDMI 1.4b и разрешение 1920x1200

Tags: монитор, hdmi

Собираюсь прикупить к ноутбуку внешний монитор, пал выбор на монитор с разрешение 1920х1200. До этого хотел взять монитор с разрешением 2к, но техническая поддержка марки ноутбука сказала, что в моем ноутбуке установлен порт  hdmi 1.4b, который к сожалению не сможет поддерживать 60hz в 2к. 
Вопрос, раз 2к не может, то сможет ли в разрешение 1920х1200 поддерживать 60hz? В стандартных в full hd то понятно что будет, ибо на ноуте такое разрешение. 
Беру исключительно для работы

Comment: FullHD и есть 2к. Или ты имеешь в виду 4к?

Comment: @Эникейщик ну первый раз выбор пал на монитор с разрешением 2560х1440, ну и производитель сказал что мой порт hdmi 1.4b не сможет выдавать в таком разрешении 60hz

Answer (score 0):

Частота 60Гц на 1920х1200 поддерживается с версии HDMI 1.0.